# Can't access media files in nginx

Tags: django, docker, nginx

I have a problem that I can't access any of /media files on my development instance of nginx with django. I'm getting 404 every time I do requests to /media

my nginx conf file

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name _;
    server_tokens off;
    client_max_body_size 20M;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location /api {
        try_files $uri @proxy_api;
    }

    location @proxy_api {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_set_header X-Url-Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass   http://backend:8000;
    }

    location /media {
        root /home/user/backend/media/;
    }

}
```

docker-compose

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  # Database service
  database:
    container_name: adverity-transformer-challenge-database
    image: postgres:9.6-alpine
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: transformer
      POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: trust
    ports:
      - "5433:5432"
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - djangonetwork
  # Async tasks broker service
  redis:
    container_name: adverity-transformer-challenge-redis
    image: redis:6
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    restart: unless-stopped

  # Async tasks worker
  celery:
    container_name: adverity-transformer-challenge-celery
    build:
      context: ./backend/
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.development
    image: adverity-transformer-challenge-backend
    environment:
      BROKER_URL: redis://redis:6379
      DATABASE_HOST: database
      DATABASE_USER: postgres
      DATABASE_NAME: transformer
    command: watchmedo auto-restart --pattern '*.py' --signal SIGINT --recursive -- celery -A transformer worker -l debug
    volumes:
      - ./backend/:/home/user/backend/:delegated

  # Main backend application
  backend:
    container_name: adverity-transformer-challenge-backend
    build:
      context: ./backend/
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.development
    image: adverity-transformer-challenge-backend
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    environment:
      BROKER_URL: redis://redis:6379
      DATABASE_HOST: database
      DATABASE_USER: postgres
      DATABASE_NAME: transformer
    volumes:
      - ./backend/:/home/user/backend/:delegated
      - ./frontend/:/home/user/frontend/:delegated
      - media:/home/user/backend/media
    depends_on:
      - database
      - redis
      - celery
    networks:
      - djangonetwork
    restart: on-failure
  nginx:
      container_name: adverity-transformer-challenge-nginx
      restart: unless-stopped
      build:
          context: .
          dockerfile: ./nginx/Dockerfile
          args:
              - API_BASE_URL=http://localhost/api
      ports:
          - 80:80
      volumes:
          - media:/home/user/backend/media
          - ./nginx/:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      depends_on:
          - backend
      networks:
          - djangonetwork
volumes:
    media: {}
networks:
  djangonetwork:
    driver: bridge
```

and my Dockerfile

```
FROM node:14-alpine as build
WORKDIR /app/frontend

EXPOSE 3000
COPY ./frontend/package.json ./
COPY ./frontend/package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install

ARG API_BASE_URL

ENV REACT_APP_API_BASE_URL=$API_BASE_URL

COPY ./frontend/ ./
RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:stable-alpine
COPY --from=build /app/frontend/build /usr/share/nginx/html
RUN chown nginx:nginx -R /usr/share/nginx/html/*

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

What am I doing wrong?

I tried different media volumes and I failed. I also tried specifing "alias" instead of "root" in my nginx conf.Everything failed